# Union Assigned Values in C

Tags: c, unions

Given the following union definition:

```
typedef union{
int i;
char ch;
float f;}record;



record a;
//a.i = 10;
a.ch = 'A';
//a.f = 10.56;
printf("printing a.i: %p \n", a.i);
printf("printing a.ch: %c \n", a.ch);
printf("printing a.f: %f \n", a.f);
return 0;
```

I get the following output:

printing a.i: 65
printing a.ch: A
printing a.f: 0.000000

Why does a.i not print 0 (the default value for undefined integers) but instead the ASCII value for 'A'. Does this somehow have access to a.ch??

Comment: Do you know the most important property of unions?

Comment: All members of a union *share* memory. Because of this, a union can be used for [*type- punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) where you pretend one type is another.

Comment: `0` is not the default value for undefined integers.

Comment: if the record is global, then the value is 0.

Comment: It should also be noted that the result of this depends on the system [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and how the compiler initializes (or not) the bytes that are not explicitly initialized.

Comment: `a.ch = 'A';` sets ***one byte*** in the union.

Comment: `%p` is not the correct format for an `int`, your compiler should have told you. (And please indent code correctly before posting.)

Answer (score 2):

You get 65, the code of `'A'`, because field `i` shares a portion of its space with the `char` field.

Overall, though, your program’s behavior with a local `union` is undefined, because you read the entire `int` after writing only a portion of it that overlaps with the `char`.

Initializing the `union` would fix the problem. However, there is no guarantee that the read would give you 65 in the lower byte. This behavior is implementation-specific.

Comment: 65 is the code of `A` not `a`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Right. I hate typing answers on an iPhone...

Comment: not bad for a phone answer!